# Set maven property from plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I've read some questions here about how to set a property (most of them talked about the version number for an application) from a maven plugin. 
It seems there's no easy way of doing this and the best solution I found is to have a filter.properties file which is updated from the plugin and used by the main pom file to filter the desired resources.

I tried another solution after I read this from the Maven documentation ([Maven filter plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)):

> Variables can be included in your resources. These variables, denoted
>   by the ${...} delimiters, can come from the system properties, your
>   project properties, from your filter resources and from the command
>   line.

I found interesting that variabled can be read from system properties. So, I modified my plugin to set a system property like this:

```
System.setProperty("currentVersion", appCurrentVersion);
```

However, filtered resources don't seem to read this value. 
Could anybody tell me what's wrong with this approach?

UPDATE: I'm running my plugin in the *validate* phase.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't set it as System Property, set it as Maven Project property

```
// inject the project
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
private org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject project;

// and in execute(), use it:
project.getProperties().setProperty("currentVersion", appCurrentVersion);
```

See:

- [Mojo Developer Cookbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20150509231102/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook#MojoDeveloperCookbook-StoringProperties)
- [`MavenProject` javadoc](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html)

---

An edit suggested using `Properties.put()` instead of `Properties.setProperty()`. While technically, `Properties` implements `Map`, this usage is discouraged explicitly [in the Properties javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html).

Answer (score 4):

Maven sets properties in [initialize phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). I assume that in that phase maven loads system properties. And after that maven doesn't load system properties again. If you try to add a system property after this phase than it's not loaded.

Try to run your plugin in [validate phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Comment: I'm already running the plugin in the validate phase. Sorry I didn't mention it before.