# Maven pass parameters from plugin to other plugin

Tags: maven, plugins

I am writing a maven plugin that should be run during the pre-integration and post-integration test phases. The plugin should set up and tear down a test system. The problem is that the ip of the test system is generated upon setup. But of course, the tests in the integration-test phase of e.g. the failsafe plugin should be able to connect to the correct address, that is currently only known in the pre-integration phase plugin.

Most likely I can do something with setting environment vars in the pre-integration phase and consuming those from within my tests, but I was looking for something a little more elegant, if that exists, because I don't feel like getting hit when the plugin changes the name of the env vars and so on.

Is it possible to have a maven plugin pass parameters to another maven plugin, in case the failsafe plugin? Also, could the failsafe plugin invoke its tests parameterized, so I can pass in my config?

I realize it's a rather open question because I am not really sure what the possibilities are.

Kasper

Comment: Why not using a usual integration tests via TestNG or JUnit and using maven-failsafe-plugin? And what kind of integration tests are you trying to write? Related to Docker ?

Comment: I would like to use the maven failsafe plugin. But I need something specific to bring up and teardown my environment. This is homebrew stuff specific to the company, so no plugin that exists, I'll need to write that, that is not really the issue. The issue is that the way the in-house stuff works is that after setup it tells you an ip where your env is running. That ip address changes per setup so I need to communicate to my tests and teardown. I don't see how to do that exactly in failsafe, so part of my question actually :-)

Comment: With maven-failsafe-plugin you can simply write tests which a setup() or tearDown method ( or things like @Before... from TestNG) to setup the environment with manual implemented code...The port can be either got via buildhelper-maven-plugin or via Jenkins CI solution....

Comment: True, I have a working setup/teardown thing. The problem is that it should be run only once for all these types of integration tests. That's why hooking into the maven pre-integration/post-integration phases looked like the best idea.

Comment: Maybe compare it with having to setup and teardown a database before tests are run, but I only know where the database runs as soon as the setup phase is done (and my tests need to do contact it of course), and the setup phase takes sufficiently long for us to want to have this done once per test run of all tests that need that database. So I would like to pass info from the maven plugin to the jvm running the tests, and I prefer not to have to write and read extra files containing the address of this database, if possible.

Comment: Than you should use an appropriate testing framework like TestNg which supports such things with `@BeforeGroup`, `@BeforeTest` etc. ?

Comment: This is not my own project, I am not allowed to change or add test frameworks just like that. Anyway, I think I have explained my original question. While I really appreciate the suggestions you have made (I did not know about @BeforeGroup, that might be interesting in another project), they are not really getting me closer to an answer to my original question concerning passing info between maven plugins and source code.

Comment: If you're writing plugins, you might try [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553530/set-maven-property-from-plugin). But if you're just starting a proc in pre-IT, then what I'm doing is using `exec-maven-plugin` during the post-IT phase to execute `pkill -f ...` to terminate the proc.