# Property not defined in parent and child POMs but still accessible in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

In a project we have a property named timestamp, it is not defined in parent and child POMs but still accessible in a pom.xml. Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please paste the child pom

Comment: It could be set up by some plugin? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553530/set-maven-property-from-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is either set by a plugin (like https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/timestamp-property-mojo.html) or passed into the build as command line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Is it probably in the archetype where the maven project is created from?